# How to store UTC datetime/timestamp and time zone in Presto for easy local time conversion?

Tags: timezone, presto

I want to store a UTC datetime in the format `2012-10-31 01:00:00` (so without explicit UTC offset or indication of the timezone) alongside another column indicating the associated timezone. The table currently would look like

```
+---------------------+---------------+
|      utc_time       |   timezone    |
+---------------------+---------------+
| 2012-10-31 01:00:00 | Europe/Berlin |
+---------------------+---------------+
```

I'm struggling to convert that UTC time in local format, the only workaround currently found is to use

```
at_timezone(cast(date_format(utc_time, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s UTC') as TIMESTAMP),timezone)
```

or to store the date with the timezone offset included. I would expect however to be able to use `at_timezone()` without having to explicitly include the offset/timezone in the timestamp.

What's the proper way to store a UTC timestamp alongside the timezone in Presto?

Thanks

Comment: What connector are you using? 
What are you asking about -- _writing_ (storing) or _reading_ the data?

Comment: I'm using jdbc connection and my question is primarily related to storing, of course then the goal is to make reading and conversion to local time more straightforward. Thanks.
Edit: I'm currently storing in the above way, but I'm not sure that's the correct way to do it.

Comment: So i understand you're writing INSERTs in Presto and storing data in a JDBC connector. What does the input look like? A `timestamp`? A data passed via prepared statement?

Comment: Yeah apologies for the poor description, I'm very new to this. The input is indeed a simple timestamp as you see it in the post. That timestamp is in implicitly in UTC format, so equivalent to eg. `2012-10-31 01:00:00+00:00` and `2012-10-31 01:00:00 UTC`.

Comment: Timestamp is always tricky because this single word can have a few different meanings. Did you try setting `experimental. legacy-timestamp=false` in config.properties? (See https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/37 for additional info). Then you would probably not need to use `at_timezone` (depending on the column type in PostgreSQL)

Comment: mm that doesn't seem to work and I wouldn't know how that could help. My goal is to still have the UTC time but easily convert it to local time when needed. Ultimately, `timestamp` is the type set in the table schema. I'm curious, considering my use-case how would you personally store a UTC date-time and a timezone?

Comment: Some databases support `timestamp with time zone` type which preserves both: point in time _and_ timezone. (eg Oracle does, eg PostgreSQL does not). Support for political (named) zone is varying. So I'd keep timezone separate, as varchar. You should treat the remaining component as regular `timestamp` and store just that: `INSERT INTO t (ts, z) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2012-10-31 01:00:00', 'Europe Warsaw')`.

Comment: btw SO tells me to "avoid extended discussions in comments", so I use this opportunity to invite you to Presto Community Slack (https://prestosql.io/slack.html).